# How to correctly change value of input form to be noticed by "change" event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create keyboard for input extra symbols in dynamically created fields. I'm using on() function to handle blur and change events of input form. I'd like to input special chars on caret position. Is it possible to make it without using global variables?
Currently change is noticed if I add letters by keyboard and then loose focus or press enter, or if I type (letter and then special character) || (special character and then special character) without loosing blur or even pressing enter.

```
  // checking click targets
  var clicky;
  $(document).mousedown(function(e) {
    clicky = $(e.target);
  });

  // handling dbclick and enter press
  $(document).on("dblclick", "input#word", function (){
    $(this).parent().parent().css('background-color', setOnEditColor);
    $(this).prop("readonly", false);
    $(this).keypress(function(e) {
      if(e.which == 13) {
        $(this).focusout();
      }
    });
  });

  // handling blur on input form
  $(document).on("blur", "input#word", function (e){
    lastFocus = $(this);

    // checking if keyboardLetter element is clicked,
    // if yes I want to keep focus on current input
    if(clicky.attr('class') == 'keyboardLetter'){
      return false;
    }
    $(this).prop("readonly", true);
    $(this).parent().parent().css('background-color', setDefaultColor);
    // $(this).trigger("change");
  });

  // onChange is triggered on blur
  $(document).on("change", "input#word", function (){
    saveChanges($(this).closest('tr').attr('id'), $(this).val(), 1);
  });




//clicking on special characters
    $(document).on("click", ".keyboardLetter", function (){
      pos = $(lastFocus).caret(); //getting caret position of focused input
      lastFocus.val(lastFocus.val().insertAt(pos, $(this).text().trim()));
      $(lastFocus).caret(pos+1);
    });
```

Comment: Can you create a jsbin or jsfiddle?  Would be helpful to see your html too.

Answer (score 0):

Call [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/#change) after setting its value:

```
lastFocus.val(lastFocus.val().insertAt(pos, $(this).text().trim()));
$(lastFocus).change(); //this line
```

Comment: I'd love if it were so easy- the problem is I'd like to call saving function

`saveChanges($(this).closest('tr').attr('id'), $(this).val(), 1);`

only after blur and only if changes were made. Do you know which event is triggered after pressing keyboard keys, I'd rather like to use this one, to notice .on("change")?

Comment: `keydown()` and `keyup()` and there is also `keypress()`.

Comment: Unfortunately none of them does affect .on("change") of input like the real keyboard does. :(

Comment: Well, triggering a `keypress` event isn't going to cause a trigger of `change()`.  I must confess I am not sure what you're trying to accomplish and why invoking `change()` won't work.

Comment: Calling change() is calling saveChanges() every time when element (special character) is clicked- saveChanges is calling ajax to save data in database - I want avoid it. 
When using keyboard to input letters, change() is called only if value is different in compare to original.

Comment: Oh! Store the last-value-sent-to-AJAX.  Compare the current value with the last value, if different, update last value and send.

Comment: Thanks, I think it's the only way. I wanted to avoid storing strings in variables, anyway .on("change") will not do the job this time. :)

Comment: A good place to store the old value is in a data-attribute of the each element. I have experienced this kind of challenge before and `data-attributes` came in handy. You just have to coordinate when to store values and when those values become 'old'! :)